# Как тестировать работу с Image(Javafx)

Tags: javafx, junit

Проект Javafx
Хотел сделать тест на создание картинки, хотя бы размеры.

Столкнулся с проблемой тестирвания работы Image в JUnit.
Не получается работать с Image без запуска формы(наследник Application).

Comment: а в чем необходимость или потребность в картинке в тестах?

Comment: Происходит масштабирование и сохранение изображения, хочу знать, что отработало, хотя бы размер посмотреть

Comment: Сохраняйте на диск и потом считывайте при помощи File.

Comment: Не получается работать с Image без запуска формы(наследник Application).

Comment: Напишите код так, что бы сохранение было без Image, а с File классом. И протестируйте. UI не нужен будет.

Comment: На Image много завязано, поэтому хочу тестить с ним.